# Community wiki checkbox

Tags: support, community-wiki

Am I blind or is the `community wiki` checkbox missing ?

(I'm asking because I was trying to convert [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/443/mysql-or-postgresql)).

Comment: I also don't see a need for this question to be CW. It is asking about the major differences of 2 Drupal database backends, that can be answered objectively.

Comment: I would think so too, but I doubt a singe post will list all reasons: it's most likely going to be multiple answers/authors that will make the full answer to the question.

Comment: Furthermore, not all reasons that differ between database apply to drupal, it is/was more a guide to requirements that would indicate which engine fits better than the other due to what Drupal modules one uses, it's not a "mysql vs posgres" thread. But it's ok, I guess optimization is a too advanced topic for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Questions can no longer be made community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192) by the author, you have to flag a moderator and ask for the questions to be made CW. Answers can still be made community wiki as usual.

Comment: I see, ok thank you

Answer (score 2):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.